# How to measure angle between two vectors in Paraview

Tags: paraview

In post processing of the simulation results in which helicity density is already computed, I am required to measure the angle between velocity vector and vorticity vector. Helicity is nothing but the scalar product of velocity and vorticity. Can someone please provide some insights of how this can be done in Paraview ?

Answer (score 0):

Filters -> Calculator

```
vel_x*vort_x + vel_y*vort_y + vel_z*vort_z
```

Apply.

Comment: Dear Mr. Mathieu Westphal, I am a newbie to Paraview. Please correct me if I am wrong. In the above formula, we are basically multiplying the components of velocity with the corresponding components of vorticity and then summing up. How are we calculating the angle between velocity and vorticity by doing this?

Comment: no idea, in your question you say you ant to compute the scalar product.

Comment: I am sorry for the the wrong framing of the question. in the question I wanted to say that results of a simulation in which helicity is already computed is given to me. I have defined helicity. I would like to measure the angle between velocity and vorticity. I asked how can this be done in Paraview? My question boils down to how to measure the angle between two vectors (say velocity and vorticity) given that you have the results of a simulation which have already computed them. ( I have corrected my mistake in the question. I am sorry for the inconvenience)

Comment: Implement this in the calculator then : https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-i-calculate-the-angle-between-two-vectors